# DAX: Is there a way to use DATEADD with FIRSTDATE to show the day prior to the FIRSDATE shown in the context?

Tags: powerbi, dax, dateadd

I am facing a bit of a challenged in DAX when creating a dashboard in Power BI.

I have got this very simple table (called 'Balance Table' giving a date and a corresponding balance for each of the dates

| Date | Balance |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-12-28 | 20 |
| 2020-12-29 | 15 |
| 2020-12-30 | 30 |
| 2020-12-31 | 50 |

I've got a date slicer that allow selecting a date range from 2020-12-29 up to 2020-12-31.

I need to show the opening balance depending on the context selected in the slicer.

The opening balance of a day being the balance of the previous day.
i.e.

when selecting 2020-12-29    2020-12-31 in the slicer it needs to show me the balance of 20 from 2020-12-28

when selecting 2020-12-30    2020-12-31 in the slicer it needs to show me the balance of 15 from 2020-12-29

when selecting 2020-12-31    2020-12-31 in the slicer it needs to show me the balance of 30 from 2020-12-30

I have tried to use the below DAX formulas, but I don't get any result (no Blank, no NA, no Error messages, just literally a white space with nothing written in it):

CALCULATE(SUM('Balance Table'[Balance]),FIRSTDATE(DATEADD('Balance Table'[Date],-1,DAY)))
CALCULATE(SUM('Balance Table'[Balance]),DATEADD(FIRSTDATE('Balance Table'[Date]),-1,DAY))

However when I use the exact same formulas to give me the balance of the day following the FIRSTDATE of the context, i.e.

CALCULATE(SUM('Balance Table'[Balance]),FIRSTDATE(DATEADD('Balance Table'[Date],1,DAY)))
CALCULATE(SUM('Balance Table'[Balance]),DATEADD(FIRSTDATE('Balance Table'[Date]),1,DAY))

I get the expected results, more precisely:
when selecting 2020-12-28    2020-12-31 in the slicer it shows me 15 (balance of 2020-12-29) and so on...

I don't understand why the formulas work when using them for the day following the FIRSTDATE of the context with the argument 1
but they don't work when using the argument -1 to give the day prior to the FIRSTDATE of the context.

How can I show the balance of day prior to the FIRSTDATE of my context?

I've done a bit of research but could not find any answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the -1 is not working is that FIRSTDATE is working in its current context. So when you filter between the 2 dates of 30-31, your firstdate -1 of the 29th is not in this selection so it will not work.

Try this:

LOOKUPVALUE('Balance Table'[Balance],'Balance Table'[Date], DATEADD(FIRSTDATE('Balance Table'[Date]),-1,DAY))

Comment: Thanks for your response.
It seems to work fine for the example I gave you with four dates in Dec.
However when I apply it to the full model where there is several months, it does not work for the months following Dec 2020 (i.e. Jan 2021, Feb 2021. etc.)

Comment: That is strange, we do a lookup on date .. Are you sure your Date column is of type Date and not a string?

Answer (score 0):

We can achive this by removing filter context ( ALL(Table) ):

```
BalancDayBeforeSelect = 
var __min = CALCULATE( min(Tabela[Date]), ALLSELECTED(Tabela)) -1
var __balance = CALCULATE( sum(Tabela[Balance]), FILTER( ALL('Tabela'),  __min =  Tabela[Date]))
return
__balance
```

sample table:

[image]

Output view:

[image]